# Problem with ListContourPlot and log scaling

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Good day to everyone.

I have some strange problem with `ListContourPlot` function combined with Log scaling.

For example, I build a table, like:

`A = ParallelTable[{a, b, Log[1 + (b/a)]}, {a, 1, 20, 1.}, {b, {10^-3., 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^3}}];`

And ask Mathematica to plot a contour plot:

`ListContourPlot[Flatten[A, 1], PlotRange -> Automatic]`

[image: pic1]

Looks nice, but I see that the vertical axe needs to be scaled with a log-scaling function:

`ListContourPlot[Flatten[A, 1], PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> 2, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log", None}, DataRange -> {{1, 20}, {10^-3, 10^3}}]`

And get something that has no sense to me.

[image: pic2]

So, where is the catch, what went wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Here is an [attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FGua.png).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `DataRange` in this case, instead use `PlotRange` like this

```
ListContourPlot[Flatten[A, 1], 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 20}, {10^-3, 10^3}, All}, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  InterpolationOrder -> 2, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log", None}]
```

[image]